# React Native Code Push not building with Android but working for iOS

Tags: android, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I have Code Push working with iOS perfectly. But after setting up an Code Push account for Android and setting up Android Studio I get the following error when I run: `react-native run-android`

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-code-push:processReleaseResources'.
> at index 4
```

I'm using versions

    `"react-native": "0.35.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "^1.15.0-beta",`

with Android Studio setup with instructions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) exactly.

No one else seems to be experiencing this error.

All of my code is here: https://github.com/Laybium/laybium

Also for the `MainApplication.java` file I edited based on these [instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#plugin-installation-android---manual) where in the `/node_modules` folder which seems weird. Did I need to duplicate the file in the root folder or somewhere like in iOS?

Comment: What OS are you performing the Android build on?